# How to use a handlebars #each helper with YAML front matter

Tags: yaml, handlebars.js, assemble

I am using assemble.io to automate my frontend development, and want to use YAML front matter to create a simple nav menu.

The HTML I want to achieve is this:

```
<li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
```

I think the correct handlebars markup is this:

```
      {{#each sublinks}}
      <li><a href="#{{section}}">{{section}}</li>
      {{/each}}
```

But what's the correct YFM? I have started with this but know the syntax isn't correct:

```
---
sublinks:
  - section: link1, link2
---
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a template like this:

```
{{#each sublinks}}
<li><a href="#{{section}}">{{section}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

You'd want a data structure like this:

```
sublinks = [
    { section: 'link1' },
    { section: 'link2' },
    //...
]
```

and in YAML, that would look like:

```
sublinks:
  - section: link1
  - section: link2
```

You should also be able to use this YAML:

```
sublinks:
  - link1
  - link2
```

with this template:

```
{{#each sublinks}}
<li><a href="#{{.}}">{{.}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

---

Your YAML corresponds to a data structure like this:

```
sublinks = [
    { section: 'link1, link2' }
]
```

and that's not terribly useful unless you want to split the `'link1, link2'` string using a Handlebars helper.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @mu's great answer, you could also do it like this:

Given this YAML front matter:

```
---
sublinks:
  - href: link/to/foo
    text: Foo Text
  - href: link/to/bar
    text: Bar Text
  - href: link/to/baz
    text: Baz Text
---
```

Your templates would look like this:

```
{{#each sublinks}}
  <li><a href="#{{href}}">{{text}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Note that the YAML specification also allows a syntax that is more JavaScript-object-like:

```
---
sublinks:
  - {href: link/to/foo, text: Foo Text}
  - {href: link/to/bar, text: Bar Text}
  - {href: link/to/baz, text: Baz Text}
---
```

Comment: Hi Jon, is it mandatory to write the json-like on a single line after the dash (`- {href: link/to/foo, text: Foo Text}`), or we can split it on more lines? I'm used to write every key/value on its own line, to improve readability ;)

Comment: YAML 1.2 is a superset of JSON. You can expect valid JSON to be recognized as valid YAML. So yes, you can make your YAML less readable by making it look more like JSON ;), but only if you follow the whitespace formatting rules of YAML.

Comment: Thank you @jonschlinkert, I think I will stay on YAML syntax, after all ;)